# How to separate unit test code with production code

Tags: unit-testing, blackberry

I have my application and unit tests in a single code base. I have got alternate entry points which when invoked, will run just the tests, which is all good. I have the test code inside the production code which I am a bit hesitant to have it there. How do I separate the unit test code to a separate project ? If that's not possible, what's the best recommended way to separate the unit tests from the production code?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a library project?  Where the main application is in a library, and the unit test project depends on that lib?  Incidentally, if you **also** find yourself with a few instances of small snippets of test code that are actually in production .java files (e.g. a single boolean flag, or an alternate constructor that only is used in unit tests), then keep in mind that BlackBerry does support preprocessor directives.  Use sparingly, but they can be a useful tool.

Comment: @Nate I wanted to know if there is a recommended way of separating the test logic from the production code? From what i understand, I can use preprocessors, or make a jar of main application and use it in a test project?

Comment: The philosophy of unit tests they should run as much as possible. If you run them in sim/device I would rather call that more integration tests. About the test you could move them separate and have another app instance which will include your test and production code. The separation would be really easy if you have automated build. We keep them in "test" folder near "src" folder. But they use same packages as production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not using BBUnit (neither do I, for several reasons). So unless your main project is a library, you can't just create a separate test project containing just the tests, which would be the preferred way (Android does exactly that). So you probably have all the test code in the main project. Then instead of using alternate entry points, why don't you just use preprocess directives? These can be switched on and off from the BlackBerry Application Descriptor.